# Which 414 status line is correct?

Tags: http, rfc

I have three types of this 414 error:
1.

```
414 Request-URI Too Long
```

2. 

```
414 Request-URI Too Large
```

3. 

```
414 URI Too Long
```

Which is the correct one to use depending on the RFCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are correct.

Even

```
414 GO AWAY
```

or

```
414 OK
```

or

```
414
```

would be (where in the last case, a trailing SP is needed).

Comment: Wow.  but in the newest RFC 7231 it seems that they changed it from Request-URI Too Long to URI Too Long

Comment: Also, are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.